# Visual block mode does not select the entire line

Tags: windows, vim

I have lines as below.

[image]

I am not able to select the all the lines in full. How do i do it?

I don't want to use visual line selection mode, because if i copy and paste in line selection maode, they won't start from the the same column

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>$</kbd> will select to the end of each line.

Also, if you `:set virtualedit+=block` you will be able to move the cursor past the end of the line when in visual block mode.